# Magento 2 : After upgrade to Magento 2.3.3 version

Tags: magento2.3.3

Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addIsSaleableAttributeToFilter()

Does anyone have an idea about it ??

Comment: Can you paste your function?

Comment: which Magento version `2.2.3` or  `2.3.3`? Specify right version.

Answer (score 1):

Your theme is probably using somewhere
'addAttributeToFilter'

Something like this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
```

Change it to something like:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', [1], 'left')
```

Best run search thru your modules and theme  files with this addAttributeToFilter

Reference with simillar issue:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Error-after-indexing-after-upgrade-to-2-3-3/td-p/144500